# Docker image deployment in Azure container specify kafka Ssl location in appSettings

Tags: c#, docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

In appsettings.Production.json, I have a consumer settings that specify the cert file

```
"SslCaLocation": "cacert.pem"
```

In deploying the image using Azure container service, it's not able to find the path.  I've tried using "./cacert.pem" since its a linux OS in azure, it should take current path.  I also tried the COPYDIR path of /app in the docker file but same issue on deployment.

This is deploying a dotnet core application in azure container instance.

**Any body else had the same problem and how it was resolved?**

**Config**

```
{
  "consumer": {
    "bootstrapservers": "code-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net:9093", //specify your kafka broker address
    "groupid": "notification-ms",
    "enableautocommit": true,
    "statisticsintervalms": 5000,
    "sessiontimeoutms": 6000,
    "autooffsetreset": 1,
    "enablepartitioneof": true,
    "SecurityProtocol": 3,
    "SaslMechanism": 1, //Plain
    "SaslUsername": "$ConnectionString",
    "SaslPassword": "Endpoint=sb://sharpcode-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=notification-ms;SharedAccessKey=key is hidden",
    "SslCaLocation": "cacert.pem"
    //"Debug": "all"
  }
```

**ERROR LOGS**

```
[03:10:27 FTL] Application start-up failed
System.InvalidOperationException: ssl.ca.location failed: by_file.c:254: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib: 
   at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.SafeKafkaHandle.Create(RdKafkaType type, IntPtr config, IClient owner)
   at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2..ctor(ConsumerBuilder`2 builder)
   at Confluent.Kafka.ConsumerBuilder`2.Build()
   at NewBenefits.NotificationService.ConsumerWrapper..ctor(ConsumerConfig config, String topicName) in /src/NotificationService/Services/ConsumerWrapper.cs:line 16
   at NewBenefits.NotificationService.Services.NotificationService.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in /src/NotificationService/Services/NotificationService.cs:line 33
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostedServiceExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 callback, Boolean throwOnFirstFailure)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at NewBenefits.NotificationService.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/NotificationService/Program.cs:line 24
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you give a bit more detail and context to your problem? What is the JSON file that you mention? What's the Docker image? etc.

Comment: Hi Robin, I modified the post and added more info. Hope you may have some idea.

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile? And do you check if the image can run well locally?

Comment: I just guessed and add a COPY command in docker file using this command COPY ["NotificationService/cacert.pem", "NotificationService/"]   and added an ADD line in FROM base as final "ADD NotificationService/cacert.pem ."   the service in Azure container deployment was able to find the cacert path